# How can show <div> and <a> in ascending order when page loads using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some listings. At present when page loads listing is showing like

- Img 1
- Test 1
- Img 3
- Test 3
- img 2
- Test 2

When page loads, I need results like

- Img 1
- Test 1
- Img 2
- Test 2
- Img 3
- Test 3

`Img` is in `<a>` tag and `test` content is in `<div>` tag

How can order the `<div>` and `<a>` in ascending order when page loads?

In `<div>` tag there is `data-id`. In `<a>` tag there is `data-tag-id`.

**Html**

```
<figure class="image_container">
    <img src="files/maier-energie-umwelt/produkte/phantom-ruehrwerke/Phantom-1400.jpg" alt="" width="738" height="800">
    <figcaption class="caption">
    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Verschleißfester Propeller aus PA12" data-description-id="areaDesc-1" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 14.228%;top: 1.25%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker.png);" data-tag-id="1"></a>

    <div id="areaDesc-1" class="description invisible" data-id="1" style="display: block;"><p><strong>Test1</p></div>

    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Abgedeckte doppelte Gleitringdichtung" data-description-id="areaDesc-3" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 25.745%;top: 21.875%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker.png);" data-tag-id="3"></a>

    <div id="areaDesc-3" class="description invisible" data-id="3"><p>Test3</p></div>

    <a class="area center-bg hasDescription" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Optimierte Schutzschelle aus Edelstahl" data-description-id="areaDesc-2" style="width: 6.775%;height: 18.75%;left: 27.778%;top: 49.375%;background-image: url(files/maier-energie-umwelt/layout/marker-bottom.png);" data-tag-id="2"></a>

    <div id="areaDesc-2" class="description invisible" data-id="2"><p>Test2</p></div>

   </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Script**

```
$('.description').sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt(a.data-id) > parseInt(b.data-id);
    }).each(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.remove();
        $(elem).appendTo(".description");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is close to be working.

You only need to use jQuery `.data()` to access data attribute value. Note that it returns number, not string, if data attribute stores numeric value, so you don't need to parse it yourself.

You also do not need to `.remove()` element. You just need to append your item to specific container - if item is already in DOM tree, then it will automatically be detached from its current place and will be moved it to a new location. Just appending items consequently in the right order gives the desired results.

```js
$(".container > div")
  .sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).data("id") - $(b).data("id"); })
  .each(function() { $(this).appendTo(".container"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div data-id="1">1</div>
  <div data-id="3">3</div>
  <div data-id="2">2</div>
  <div data-id="9">9</div>
  <div data-id="5">5</div>
  <div data-id="4">4</div>
  <div data-id="8">8</div>
  <div data-id="7">7</div>
  <div data-id="6">6</div>
</div>
```

**Update:** in order to sort your divs together with related `<a/>` tags, you can use jQuery `.prev()` which simply takes the previous DOM element and then you can do the same operation with this link. However, it is a better idea to wrap `a` and `div` into single element, so that their relation is described in HTML, but not by their order.

```js
$(".container > div")
  .sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).data("id") - $(b).data("id"); })
  .each(function() { 
    $(this).prev().appendTo(".container");
    $(this).appendTo(".container"); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"> 
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <div data-id="1">1</div>
  
  <a href="#">Three</a>
  <div data-id="3">3</div>
  
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <div data-id="2">2</div>
  
  <a href="#">Nine</a>
  <div data-id="9">9</div>
  
  <a href="#">Five</a>
  <div data-id="5">5</div>
  
  <a href="#">Four</a>
  <div data-id="4">4</div>
  
  <a href="#">Eight</a>
  <div data-id="8">8</div>
  
  <a href="#">Seven</a>
  <div data-id="7">7</div>
  
  <a href="#">Six</a>
  <div data-id="6">6</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I used this code but <a> tag is missed from between div tags

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var yourList = $(".description");
yourList.sort(function(x, y){
    return $(x).data("id")-$(y).data("id")
});
$(".caption").append(yourList);
```

Have tested and works now, noticed a small typo.  See it working here https://jsfiddle.net/trekmp/pLyw3qg4/5/

Comment: Just out of curiosity how are you building the divs in the first place?  If its from a database could you not sort at that point?

Comment: Good question. I am using contao, it's a CMS. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I have tried this code but I have <a> tag in between <div>. After adding this code <a> tag is not showing between <div>

Comment: mmm, going to take a little more work to sort that, you just asked about the divs initially. Do you have any control over the initial output?

Comment: These content and images are adding via back-end. In front-end it is showing shuffled result.